# Uninstall Adobe AIR based Apps that installed via Internet

Tags: ubuntu, uninstall, adobe-air

I'm running Ubuntu 9.10
I have an Adobe AIR based app named Balsamiq (God, it's super slow) which I installed from Internet (so, to be clear, I don't have the original installation file). Now I want to uninstall it. How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, Adobe AIR applications on Linux are installed as native packages. So, you could locate the application, and use `dpkg`, `deb`, or `rpm` to try to remove the package.

In addition, I found [this page](http://www.knowliz.com/2009/06/how-to-uninstall-adobe-air-applications.html) that documents a number of different ways of removing installed Adobe AIR applications.